# Eval binding object in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, ado.net, eval

I'm binding the ListView with the following code.

```
List<intermediate> order = new List<intermediate>();
order = DBInteraction.GetAllActiveOrders();
lvProducts.DataSource = order;
lvProducts.DataBind();
```

my intermediate is as follow:

```
public class intermediate
{
    public product pro = new product();
    public order ord = new order();
}
```

now on frontend i'm binding the listview like:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvProducts" OnItemCommand="lvProducts_ItemCommand">
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Text='<%# Eval(ord.oID) %>'/>
        </td>...
```

same with Eval("ord.oID"). its throwing exception: 
 The name 'ord' does not exist in the current context. How to bind such object? is i'm on right path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ord.oID") %>'/>
```

Instead of this:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblID" Text='<%# Eval(ord.oID) %>'/>
```